# SQL Server connection for ALTER LOGIN c# .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, authentication, alter

This c# code just doesn't want to change Password on the server (UserID and PW will obviously be a strings for some purpose, but this is just to get it working):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ("Data Source=ServerIP;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=UserID;Password=UserPW");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("ALTER LOGIN UserID WITH PASSWORD='NewPW' OLD_PASSWORD='UserPW'", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
conn.Close();
```

Changing Password using the same command `ALTER LOGIN UserID WITH PASSWORD='NewPW' OLD_PASSWORD='UserPW'` with a Server Management studio works like a charm, so there is no problem within command line or/and permissions for this particular User.
I guess I miss something in Sql Connection line.
Already tried combinations of:

```
Initial Catalog=master;
Initial Catalog=;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
Persist Security Info=True;
```

Changing command type, using `ExecuteNonQuery();`, and many other things, but nothing seems to work.

"Google" doesn't give any valuable result, hopefully I will find my answer here, thanks for taking your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, works a treat for me:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection ("Data Source=ServerIP;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=UserID;Password=UserPW");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand ("ALTER LOGIN UserID WITH PASSWORD='NewPW' OLD_PASSWORD='UserPW'", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

You forgot to put `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after you opened the connection.  I just tested this and it successfully changed the password on my local database.

Comment: I have mention this in my initial post, anyway thanks, it works exactly in this way.

Seems like the problem was server side, adm fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

```
string queryString = @"DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(500)
               SET @sql = 'ALTER LOGIN ' + QuoteName(@loginName) + 
                    ' WITH PASSWORD= ' + QuoteName(@password, '''') 
               EXEC @sql ";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginName", loginName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
}
```

**UPDATE**

With DDL (data definition language) statements (as ALTER LOGIN) you cannot use parameters directly. That's why I'm using a dynamic SQL.

The [QuoteName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) will do proper quoting in the SQL, simply doubles any [ characters (first call) or ' characters (second call).

Comment: -2: `Quotename` is for returning object names in a correctly quoted fashion, and creating dynamic SQL for no reason opens it up to SQL injection.

Comment: Where do you see SQL Injection here ?

Comment: OK I take back the SQL injection, but why not just pass in the params without the whole construct and execute SQL?  That is the point of them.

Comment: IMO the ALTER LOGIN statement won't work with variables directly. The QuoteName will do proper quoting in the SQL, simply doubles any [ characters (first call) or ' characters (second call).

Comment: So, I rechecked and with DDL (data definition language) statements you cannot use parameters directly. That's why I'm using a dynamic SQL in my solution. There is also no SQL injection going on here, so don't see any reason for minus point.